# Flutter form - multi screens

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I need to have a registration form on app and it's quite long so how can I split the registration into 2 screens so that once you've completed the first screen you go to the next screen when yo click the next button. On the next screen all the form variables should be available form the previous page. On the second page I want to save all the variables to Google Firebase.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very simplified example of how you can have data from TextFormFields from one view pass to the next view:

```
class FirstFormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstFormPageState createState() => _FirstFormPageState();
}

class _FirstFormPageState extends State<FirstFormPage> {
  TextEditingController _firstFormFieldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _secondFormFieldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _thirdFormFieldController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: _firstFormFieldController,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _secondFormFieldController,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _thirdFormFieldController,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Next'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return SecondFormPage([
                _firstFormFieldController.text,
                _secondFormFieldController.text,
                _thirdFormFieldController.text,
              ]);
            }
          )),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SecondFormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> previousFields;

  SecondFormPage(this.previousFields);

  @override
  _SecondFormPageState createState() => _SecondFormPageState();
}

class _SecondFormPageState extends State<SecondFormPage> {
  TextEditingController _firstFormFieldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _secondFormFieldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _thirdFormFieldController = TextEditingController();

  List<String> allData = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: _firstFormFieldController,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _secondFormFieldController,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _thirdFormFieldController,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Next'),
          onPressed: submitData,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void submitData(){
    allData.addAll(widget.previousFields);
    allData.addAll([
      _firstFormFieldController.text,
      _secondFormFieldController.text,
      _thirdFormFieldController.text,
    ]);

    // Submit your data
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. I should be able to put all values into an object then pass the object to the next screen as you've shown.

Comment: Glad I could help. If an answer has fixed your issue, remember to mark it as correct. Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `onPressed` property that takes a `Voidcallback`. You can use the `Navigator` class t navigate to the next screen, for example:

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => Home(user: user
   ),                                           
  ),
 );
```

Where `Home` is the class of the second screen and the object `user` is the data sent in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.